# Why don't I need "%matplotlib inline" in my jupyter notebook?

Tags: python, matplotlib, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, ipython

I am just trying to understand why my jupyter installation does not require me to run '%matplotlib inline' (which, according to everything I've read, I should have to run that to get my plots inline in my jupyter notebook).  But the fact is, my matplotlib plots appear inline in my notebook whether I run '%matplotlib inline' or not.  I am running an anaconda install of jupyter on ubuntu under WSL, using chrome as the client to my notebook server.  jupyter --version 4.4.0 and jupyter-notebook --version 5.7.8

I've checked my ~/.jupyter/jupyter_notebook_config.py file and see nothing in there about matplotlib.

If I run the following in my notbook:

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
```

This is the output:

```
'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
```

But if I run ipython directly in my WSL ubuntu window, and then run the above I get:

```
In [1]: import matplotlib
In [2]: matplotlib.get_backend()
Out[2]: 'agg'
```

Any idea how I can determine why this works this way?  Is it perhaps part of the anaconda installation, that the kernal determines when it is running in a notebook and automatically switches the backend to 'backend_inline' ??

Thanks.  Just curious why this is working this way for me.

---

RESPONDING TO COMMENTS:

@darthbith, each of these was done with a fresh restart of the kernel:

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
'module://ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline'
```

above is same as when I don't run %matplotlib inline

now restart kernel and try %matplotlib notebook:

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib
matplotlib.get_backend()
'nbAgg'
```

Comment: I don't think this is special to Anaconda, I think this is built in to matplotlib. For a long time, Matplotlib has detected which backends are available for a particular interpreter to try to pick the most appropriate one. Just out of curiosity, which backend do you get if you do `%matplotlib inline` or `%matplotlib notebook` before you `import matplotlib`?

Comment: Na na, matplotlib will **never** select an external backend (in this case `ipykernel.pylab.backend_inline` by itself). This is clearly something jupyter/IPython is doing.

Comment: To @darthbith -- I have responded to your curiousty in an edit to the question

    (because I thought i could not format code
    in a comment)

Comment: So 
it looks like [it's hardcoded](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/7267f5da77300ab6a46e95f00be0eaddbe9c389a/ipykernel/kernelapp.py#L402) in ipykernel, which [gets called](https://github.com/ipython/ipykernel/blob/7267f5da77300ab6a46e95f00be0eaddbe9c389a/ipykernel/kernelapp.py#L489) upon initialization. But this may only be half the truth because in principle `IPython` has a [`InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib`](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/config/options/kernel.html#configtrait-InteractiveShellApp.matplotlib) configuration parameter.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest -- Thanks!